# Adding function at run time in PHP classes

Tags: php, class, dynamic-programming

I have class

```
class a{
     var $test;
}
```

I have lots of functions in files. Each file having its own function like

```
File1.php contains function File1(){}
```

There are 50+ files for function.
I want to dynamically add onliy one function at runtime, So that final class structure like this

```
class a{
var $test;
function File1(){
}
}
```

Comment: [This has already been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011910/how-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-php)

Comment: Yes but in the question, We can extend the function with closure but we cant modify the variables of class with closure defination..

Comment: why would you want to do that in the first place? Point being why not just add all the methods you need?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly