# Redeclaring class in php file where now generated a function

Tags: php

There is a file myclass.php:

```
<?php
class Myclass {
    public static function Fun1() {

    }
}
```

and i try to make an own framework where to use a code generation:

```
$class = "MyClass";
$function = "Fun1";
$fname = "myclass.php"
if (class_exists($class) && !method_exists($class, $functionName)) {
    $current = file_get_contents($fname);
    if ($current) {
        $strIndex = strlen($current);
        while ($strIndex-- && $current[$strIndex] != "}");//removing the last '}'
        $current = substr($current, 0, $strIndex);
        $current .= "\tpublic static function $functionName() {\n";//there inserting the new function
        $current .= "\n";
        $current .= "\t}\n";
        $current .= "}\n";
        $current .= "\n";
        file_put_contents($fname, $current);
        require $fname;//I load the file again, but how to redeclare the class?
    }
}
```

.. and i get a message: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MyClass in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\index.php on line 12. Thank you.

Comment: You can't have 2 declarations of the class with the same name in the same namespace. How would the engine know which one of the 2 you intended when using it?

Comment: You are trying to add a method to an existing class? That's very un-PHP-like (more like Ruby or JavaScript). Runkit allows it: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php

Comment: See also: [How to add a method to an existing class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011910/how-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That's not un-PHP-like, that's very bad OO. Subclassing `Myclass` would be much better in design, wouldn't it?

Comment: @wumm Indeed bad OO, and that's why the Decorator is suggested in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

"Extend" Myclass

```
class MyMyClass extends MyClass
{
    public function SomeNewMethod() {
    }
}
```

see also [Method Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):