# "Generate" class methods from an array?

Tags: php, methods

Not sure if this makes any sense but I'm having a case of `DRY` since I have to create around 20 classes. (This is for Laravel's eloquent ORM where each class represents a table):

Each class looks like this:

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        array_push($this->appends, 'item');
        array_push($this->hidden, 'item_id', 'items');
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Item', 'id', 'item_id');
    }

    public function getItemAttribute()
    {
        return $this->items->name;
    }
}
```

Notice the repetition of `item`, (if it makes any sense here) how can I "generate" all this from an array of "items"? What I imagine it could be:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $fields = ['item', 'price'];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        array_push($this->appends, $field);
        array_push($this->hidden, $field.'_id', str_plural($field));

        // now create our functions, i have no idea what i'm doing here
        public function str_plural($field)
        {
            return $this->hasOne(ucfirst($field), 'id', $field.'_id');
        }

        public function get{ucfirst($field)}Attribute()
        {
            return $this->{str_plural($field)}->name;
        }
 }
```

Comment: You could use [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to get the calls. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011910/how-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-php) helps as well

Comment: Why is your `getItemAttribute()` method in the `Child` class and not simply accessed using the "magic" properties in the `Item` class?

Comment: @Mark I'm not too familiar with "magic" properties can you elaborate further or show an example?

Comment: Laravel/Eloquent automatically creates the properties for your model "magically", there's plenty of examples in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)